# How to apply the same materials to models over different .blend files

Tags: materials

I made an anthropomorphic creature in Blender, and the mesh is comprised of multiple objects (which means separate textures for a single mesh.) I am creating a rigged variant of the model in a new .blend file.

Is there a way for me to transfer the materials from the old model to the new model seamlessly?

My model: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zXHi3ODmpyiEBVW5QPrUanIEgcA9k4mH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Showing pictures of your setup and explaining how you attempted to transfer materials would help to figure out a solution. Additionally, if you could upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here, it will help even more.

Comment: Sorry, @L0Lock, I really want to upload my file but uh, kinda embarrassed cause it's a protogen.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zXHi3ODmpyiEBVW5QPrUanIEgcA9k4mH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You still need to edit your post and add more detail about what you tried exactly. We can't post answers without that.